# How do you incorporate seasonal differencing into a regression in R?

Tags: r, time-series, stationarity

I've spent like 3 hours trying to figure this out.  I've found millions of articles on how to remove trends and seasonality in a time series data.  However, none of the articles tell me how to incorporate this into a linear regression equation in R without some fancy package.

To remove trend, you can add time to your regression.  For example:

lm(y ~ t)

where y is your data and t is just the time associated with each data point.  Most times you'll include a lag1 regressor so it'll be:

lm(y ~ t + y_(t-1))

How do you add seasonal differencing into the equation - let's say you have monthly data and the cycle occurs yearly.  So you would want a lag12 difference.  How do I incorporate this into the lm formula above?

Comment: Since you just have four seasons, is there a reason you don't try incorporating a random factor by using `lmer` in the `lme4` R package? It is not too much more work to do so. A lag12 difference would have a slightly different effect than what I think of as "seasonal differences", IMHO.

Comment: Errr, what's wrong with 'fancy packages"?

Comment: becuase i'm trying to learn how to use r first before i start taking shorcuts by using packages.  and while packages are fine for myself at home, not sure if i use it professionally one day, i'll be able to use the same packages

Answer (score 3):

If you have monthly data, and you want to deal with seasonality, the simplest thing to do would be to add a regression term that is a categorical variable specifying the month (which would manifest as eleven indicator variables in the model).  This way you account for a monthly effect of any form.  For example, if you have three categorical variables `x1`, `x2` and `x3` and a `month` variable, you would code your regression as:

```
MyModel <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + factor(month), data = MyData);
```

The advantage of this simple factor model is that you do not have to specify a parametric form for the posited seasonal effect - it is instead fit as a set of category effects.  It takes up eleven degrees-of-freedom, but that is usually not too costly in most data sets.  In my view, this is generally a better starting point than using an auto-regression with a lag of 12 months, though you should check your residuals for auto-correlation after you have fit the model, to see if the latter is needed.

Comment: 11 degrees of freedom may indeed be quite a lot. In addition, discretizing time into months yields a stepwise function with hard steps between months, which is often ecologically invalid. I'd much rather recommend periodic [tag:splines], which address seasonality with far fewer parameters, and smoothly. (Funnily enough, I just reviewed a paper where I gave pretty much the same comment.)

Comment: Spline methods are also good, but the post by the OP specified monthly data, so I'm presuming that aggregation into months is an inherent structural feature of the data.  If that is ecologically invalid, I presume the problem lies in aggregation into months, rather than the treatment as a factor variable.  Anyway, it really depends on the data you have, so I'm just going by the description of the OP.

Comment: i already have a dummy variable for that but the acf plot is still showing autocorrelation.  i want to try differencing and see what happens